# Estou tentando transformar meu laço FOR em uma função com recursão

Tags: javascript

A ideia é o seguinte: "Um função que irá verificar o número de letras B que existe em uma determinada palavra", realizei isso com laço FOR e estou tentando passar para uma function com recursão. Alguém pode me apontar o erro por favor

```
var numB = 0;
var count2=0;

function countBss(palavra){
    if(palavra.length==count2){
        return numB;
    }
    else if(palavra.charAt(count2)=="B"){
        numB += 1;
    }
    else{
        count2+=1;
        return countBss(palavra);
    }
}

console.log(countBss("BBB"));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando trabalhar com funções recursivas, tente garantir que em todas as condições que precisa ela seja chamada. No seu caso, após a verificação se a letra da posição corresponde à "B", você deve chamá-la novamente para que o próximo caractere seja verificado. Segue o exemplo:
var numB = 0;
var count2=0;

```
function countBss(palavra){
    if(palavra.length==count2){
        return numB;
    }
    else if(palavra.charAt(count2)== "B" || palavra.charAt(count2)== "b"){
        numB += 1;
        count2+=1;
        return countBss(palavra);
    }
    else{
        count2+=1;
        return countBss(palavra);
    }
}

console.log(countBss("BBB"));
```

Adicionei mais uma validação, dessa vez para o caractere "b", tornando a condição "case insensitive".